# php - how to parse XML returned by an api call from a website?

Tags: php, api, redirect

I am currently developing a website which requires an API call to a social plugin website to obtain a user token.  With the user token, I can call the website's login window and have the user log in with his/her login credentials to allow my app to obtain the required data.

When 1) I make the API call to the website, 2) it returns the URL with a user token in XML as shown below:

1)

```
<a href="<?php echo "http://xxxxx.net/api/get_auth_url.xml?akey=$myAppKey" ?>" target="_blank">Login</a>
```

2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<auth_token> <url>http://xxxxx.net/api/start_auth?token=7x1x81xfxxxxx5bxxxx3dx45trsda</url> <token>7x1x81xfxxxxx5bxxxx3dx45trsda</token> </auth_token>
```

However, I am relatively new to PHP and not sure what will be the right approach to handle this XML returned, and to redirect the website to "http://xxxxx.net/api/start_auth?token=7x1x81xfxxxxx5bxxxx3dx45trsda".  Once redirected, I can have user to log in and get the information I needed.

I have tried using curl method as shown below, but I am not familiar with parsing the result of curl_exe() and redirecting the site using the parsed value.  I have not been able to get it working yet, but I think there should be more php native way to handle the returned XML and to use that serialized XML objects for redirecting the website.

```
<?php $ch = curl_init(); ?>
<?php curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxxx.net/api/get_auth_url.xml?akey=$myAppKey"); ?>
<?php curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); ?>
<?php $store = curl_exec($ch); ?>
<?php curl_close($ch); ?>
```

Any feedback will be much appreciated.
WL

Answer (score 3):

i'd give [SimpleXMLElement](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) a shot once you've got your XML String (for which I'd also use `curl_exec()`, by the way) ...

```
$authTokenXml = new SimpleXMLElement( $store );
$authUrl = $authTokenXml->url
```

and now you can use `$authUrl` in any way you like, e.g. sending a http redirect header:

```
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
```

or with another CURL.

Hope that helps!

(btw. you don't need the `<?php`-Tags in every line. It starts a php block, actually)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the [SimpleXML documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Thanks.  Using SimpleXMLElement( ) did not the job.